# Загрузка файлов с помощью ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript, файлы, php

Javascript:

```
    var file = this.files[0];
    if(!file) return;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/file.php',
        data: 'cover='+file,
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

Как сохранить файл на сервере?

На `print_r($_FILES);` получаю Array( )

На `print_r($_POST);` получаю Array( [cover] => [object File] )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если только для современных браузеров (Chrome 10+, FF4+, Safari 6+, Opera 12+, IE10+), то так:

```
var formData = new FormData;
$.each(this.files, function (i, file){
   formData.append('files[]', file);
});

$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (result){ /*__*/ }
});
```

Для полной поддержки (вплоть для IE6), могу предложить библиотеку [FileAPI](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/).